# Make a div with background with lines in 50 degrees angle

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to implement a **background** with inclined lines into a `div` or `table`. To represent that element is finished.
like this example: [Background](https://previews.123rf.com/images/kumer/kumer1603/kumer160300042/54021808-Vector-el-modelo-rayado-diagonal-sin-fisuras-fondo-blanco-y-negro-Foto-de-archivo.jpg)

How can acchive that with **CSS**?

I dont want an image as background, because i need change attributtes by **JQuery** and im ussing Bootstrap

Comment: Question - Why don't you want to use a background image?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: From the close options: Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are **off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

Comment: @Archer i dont want an image because i can change CSS values by JQuery and i dont need different images, only change the `color` or other atributtes. Make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```css
.wrapper {
  color: white;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #333, #333 10px, #fff 10px, #fff 20px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```